# Sleeping till NEXT Second

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I am finding often the need to very often wait until the next second to do the next operation in a series. This slows down unit tests quite considerably. So here's my question:

Instead of doing Thread.sleep(1000) is there a quicker more efficient way to sleep until the second changes to the next second?

Say the time is 1:00:89

I sleep one second to 1:01:89

I would rather continuing executing when the time hits 1:01
or as close as possible.

Is this reasonably possible? ^_^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you could do something like:

```
long millisWithinSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
Thread.sleep(1000 - millisWithinSecond);
```

It won't be exact, mind you - you may need to iterate, which is a bit messy.

However, it would be better not to have to sleep at all. Could you inject a "sleeping service" which would allow you to fake the sleeps out in tests? (I've rarely needed to do that, but I've *often* injected a fake clock to report different times.) What's the purpose of sleeping in the production code at all?

Comment: +1 for noting that you shouldn't be sleeping in unit tests/production code

Comment: @Tim Bender, I thought it was exactly the other way around - that the thread may be woken at any time, long before the sleep time is up.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I use a web service which must only be called at most once a second. If called more often, I am blocked.

Comment: @Amigable: Okay, so injecting a sleeping service is likely to be better than calling Thread.sleep directly.

Comment: @Amigable, you're right. I think I had read that from another article. Here is an SDN bug that describes why an "at least" guarantee can not be made: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5068368

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I only mentioned it as an example of where sleeping in production code is something to do. With a sleeping service, it is prettier of course.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the second", do you mean the second of the system clock? You can get the current time in milliseconds via `System.currentTimeMillis()`, then subtract that from 1000 and sleep by that amount, but keep in mind that Thread.sleep() is not perfectly accurate, so don't be surprised if you overshoot by a bit.